# Is this correct configuration of react app using vite?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom, vite

I have created a react app using vite.

This is my App.jsx

```
import './styles.css'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import About from './components/pages/About'
import Resume from './components/pages/Resume'
import Work from './components/pages/Work'
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact'
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}>
            <Route path='about' element={About}></Route>
            <Route path='resume' element={Resume}></Route>
            <Route path='work' element={Work}></Route>
            <Route path='contact' element={Contact}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
     
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is my Home.jsx

```
import NavBar from "./pages/NavBar";
import Header from "./pages/Header";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";
// import About from "./pages/About";
// import Resume from "./pages/Resume";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate("/about");
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
      <div className="d-flex1 gap-3">
        <Profile></Profile>
        <div className="w-100">
          <div className=" navbar d-flex justify-content-end">
            <NavBar></NavBar>
          </div>
          <Outlet />
          {/* <Resume></Resume> */}
          {/* <About></About> */}
          <Contact></Contact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

This is my package.json
[image]

This is My NabBar.jsx

```
import * as Lucide from "lucide-react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function NavBar() {
  const location = useLocation();

  const activeLink = location.pathname.split("/").pop();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="d-flex gap-3 card-effect mt-3 ">
          <NavLink
            to="/about"
            className={`icon  ${activeLink === "home" ? "active" : null}`}
          >
            <Lucide.HomeIcon></Lucide.HomeIcon>
            <p>Home</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/resume"
            className={`icon  ${activeLink === "resume" ? "active" : null}`}
          >
            <Lucide.FileTextIcon></Lucide.FileTextIcon>
            <p>Resume</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/work"
            className={`icon  ${activeLink === "work" ? "active" : null}`}
          >
            <Lucide.BriefcaseIcon></Lucide.BriefcaseIcon>
            <p>Work</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/contact"
            className={`icon  ${activeLink === "contact" ? "active" : null}`}
          >
            <Lucide.ContactIcon></Lucide.ContactIcon>
            <p>Contact</p>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Now when i am trying to navigate to http://localhost:5173/about, the about component wasn't rendering. I have checked multiple online sources for a solution, but I can't find any. The same implementation was working in my other project, where that project was created using create-react-app.

Comment: Your about component is commented out. I don't know if it's because you forgot to edit your question accordingly or because it's the "bug". Also why in your Home component are you redirecting to about on first render? I think it explains why it isn't working. The element in your parent route should act a layout only where you want to render every inner routes in the outlet component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `About` component (*and other routed components*) doesn't render because it's not passed to the `element` prop correctly as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. as JSX. Instead of `element={About}` it should be `element={<About />}`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="resume" element={<Resume />} />
    <Route path="work" element={<Work />} />
    <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Additional suggestion:

The `NavLink` component applies an `"active"` CSS classname by default, so there's no need to use the `useLocation` hook and recompute the matched/active link yourself manually, the `NavLink` component already knows how to do this.

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="d-flex gap-3 card-effect mt-3 ">
        <NavLink to="/about" className="icon">
          <Lucide.HomeIcon />
          <p>Home</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/resume" className="icon">
          <Lucide.FileTextIcon />
          <p>Resume</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/work" className="icon">
          <Lucide.BriefcaseIcon />
          <p>Work</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/contact" className="icon">
          <Lucide.ContactIcon />
          <p>Contact</p>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.icon {
  // link rules here
}
.icon.active {
  // active link rules here
}
```

[image: Edit is-this-correct-configuration-of-react-app-using-vite]

However, if you wanted to supply a *different* active CSS classname, then the recommended pattern is to use the [`classname` callback syntax](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#classname) and access the passed `isActive` property.

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to="/about"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    ["icon", isActive ? "customClassname" : ""].join(" ")
  }
>
  <Lucide.HomeIcon />
  <p>Home</p>
</NavLink>
```